# How to send multiple data fields via Ajax?

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax

I'm stuck: I'm trying to submit a form using AJAX, but I can't find a way to send multiple data fields via my AJAX call.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function()  {
    var status = $("#activitymessage").val();
    var name = "Ronny";
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax/activity_save.php",
      **data: "status="+status+"name="+name"**,
      success: function(msg) {...
```

I've tried all sorts of stuff:

```
data: {status: status, name: name},
```

Or even stuff like this just for testing purposes:

```
data: "status=testing&name=ronny",
```

But whatever I try, I get nothing in my `activity_save.php` thus nothing in my SQL.

So, what's the correct syntax to put more lines of data in my AJAX call?

Comment: Both of the secondary forms of handling the input data are valid.  How are you accessing this on the PHP side?  You may consider an HTTP sniffer (Fiddler on the PC, something like HTTPScoop on a Mac), which will show you exactly what is moving across the wire.

Comment: I would suggest using firebug/chrome to debug your post data.  Make sure you are getting a HTTP Code 200 and that the form data is being posted at your think it should be.  If everything looks correct with the post data, I would start trying to debug your PHP server side code.

Comment: Using firebug really helped, totally forgot about checking my page with it. :/

Comment: What is the use of ** in front and at the end of the data param?

Comment: @heinkasner, I think the ** is just there to show the reader which line the author would like to emphasize.  The ** would have to be removed when the code is ready to be saved to file!

Answer (score 283, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
data: {status: status, name: name},
```

As specified here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

So if that doesn't work, I would alert those variables to make sure they have values.

Comment: He points out specifically in the question: "i've tried all sorts of stuff:

`data: {status: status, name: name},`"

Comment: I was just pointing out the correct syntax and saying that the problem must be something else not the syntax

Comment: Seems my syntax was correct, I believe i've made a very dumb SQL mistake.

Comment: Re: syntax, note that a key name is a '-' e.g. `data: { site-name: "StackOverflow" }` won't work.

Comment: From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) *"The data option can contain either a query string of the form `key1=value1&key2=value2`, or an object of the form `{key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}`. If the latter form is used, the data is converted into a query string using jQuery.param() before it is sent."*

Answer (score 38):

You can send data through JSON or via normal POST, here is an example for JSON.

```
 var value1 = 1;
 var value2 = 2;
 var value3 = 3;   
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: "yoururlhere",
      data: { data1: value1, data2: value2, data3: value3 },
      success: function (result) {
           // do something here
      }
 });
```

If you want to use it via normal post try this

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: $('form').attr("action"),   
      data: $('#form0').serialize(),
      success: function (result) {
         // do something here
      }
 });
```

Comment: `.serialize()` is not defined!

Comment: what if we want to pass some more data along with serialize function 
Exaample: 
`$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'retrivedata.php',
       action: "c",
                id:"index",
                data: {$(this).serialize(),
                    id: "index",
      action: "c"}
});
});`

Answer (score 10):

Try with quotes:

```
data: {"status": status, "name": name}
```

It must work fine.

Comment: +1. BTW this actually 
data: {status: "status", name: "name"}

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 7):

```
var countries = new Array();
countries[0] = 'ga';
countries[1] = 'cd';
```

after that you can do like:

```
var new_countries = countries.join(',')
```

after:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Concessions.aspx/GetConcessions",
    data: new_countries,
    ...
```

This thing work as JSON string format.

Comment: This solution worked for me when trying to pass an array over ajax.  Joining it into a string was the solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This one works for me.

Here's my PHP:

```
<div id="pageContent">
  <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
  ?>
  <br/>
  <input id="vendorName_" name="vendorName_<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" value='<?php echo $row["vendorName"]; ?>'>
  <input id="owner_" name="owner_<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" value='<?php echo $row["owner"]; ?>'>
  <input id="city_" name="city_<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" value='<?php echo $row["city"]; ?>'>
  <button id="btn_update_<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">Update</button>
  <button id="btn_delete_<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">Delete</button>
  <?php
    }
  ?>
  </br></br>
  <input id = "vendorName_new" value="">
  <input id = "owner_new" value="">
  <input id = "city_new" value="">
  <button id = "addNewVendor" type="submit">+ New Vendor</button>
</div>
```

Here's my jQuery using AJAX:

```
$("#addNewVendor").click(function() {
  alert();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "create.php",
    data: {vendorName: $("#vendorName_new").val(), owner: $("#owner_new").val(), city: $("#city_new").val()},
    success: function(){
      $(this).hide();
      $('div.success').fadeIn();
      showUsers()
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

According to http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I am a beginner at ajax but I think to use this "data: {status: status, name: name}" method
datatype must be set to JSON
i.e

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
url: "ajax/activity_save.php",
data: {status: status, name: name},
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. `dataType` is the content type response you expect to get from the **server** - not what you're sending. The data you're sending will **always** be converted to `foo=bar&bar=foo`.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to AJAX and I have tried this and it works well.

```
function q1mrks(country,m) {
  // alert("hellow");
  if (country.length==0) {
    //alert("hellow");
    document.getElementById("q1mrks").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("q1mrks").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","../location/cal_marks.php?q1mrks="+country+"&marks="+m,true);
  //mygetrequest.open("GET", "basicform.php?name="+namevalue+"&age="+agevalue, true)
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
data: '{"username":"' + username + '"}',
```

I try a lot of syntax to work with laravel
it work for me for laravel 4.2 + ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
    var status = $("#activitymessage").val();
    var name = "Ronny";
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax/activity_save.php",
      data: {'status': status, 'name': name},
        success: function(msg) {...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "something.php",
    data: { "b": data1, "c": data2 },   
    dataType: "html",
    beforeSend: function() {},
    error: function() {
        alert("Error");
    },
    success: function(data) {                                                    
        $("#result").empty();
        $("#result").append(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Some explanation perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me after 2 days of head-scratching; why I couldn't get the AJaX 'data' setting to send two key/values (including a variable containing raw image data) was a mystery, but that seems to be what the **jQuery.param() function** was written for;

create a params array with your variables, without quotes:

```
var params = { key_name1: var_1, key_name2: var_2  }; // etc.

var ser_data = jQuery.param( params );   // arbitrary variable name
```

Use variable ser_data as your data value;

```
      $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '../php_handler_url.php',
       data: ser_data,
    }).success(function(response) {
       alert(response);
    });
```

Documentation is here: 
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Hope that helps!