# Requested JSON parse failed

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, parsing

By some reason there's a parsing error with the ajax code below. How could I find out what it is, and/or can someone see what's wrong?

```
$('#listElements').sortable({
        //revert: true,
        update: function(event, ui) {

            var order = [];
            $('.listObject li').each(function (e) {
                order.push($(this).attr('id'));
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.php?",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { json: order },                  error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                        alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                        alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                        alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                        alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                        alert('Time out error.');
                    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                        alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                    } else {
                        alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: parseing error in this js code, or in the resulting json text on the server?

Comment: have you tried removing the leading / on index.php?

Comment: Don't tell us what the exact problem is. It would take away all the fun of guessing! Everybody knows engineers *love* guessing.

Comment: can you debug-output your `order` variable?

Comment: Use the browsers debugging tools for JavaScript. It's often on F12

Comment: Sorry, I'm just not into AJAX so I don't know how the error messages work. Of course I've looked at the console, but there's actually no information there at all in this case.

Comment: "no information"? so where do you get the "parsing error" from?

Comment: @PiTheNumber: From the if statement in the code which I first forgot to include. Sorry!

Comment: ok, so the JSON from index.php is wrong. That means the code you posted has nothing to do with the problem. Can you post the JSON response or index.php? What browser do you use?

Comment: I use Chrome. How can I get the JSON response?

Comment: Press F12 to open the console and select Network. There you see all file loads and AJAX requests. Select index.php and have a look at Response. Or you call index.php with the needed parameter manually. Did you write index.php yourself? I also added another way to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data: { json: order } ... it's not well formatted...

Comment: I think this could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085649/ajax-multiple-data

Comment: a little more explanation!

Answer (score 1):

There is no parsing error in this JavaScript code.

Please post the response of "index.php" and the error message you got.

Have a look at the response data. Open index.php in the browser, press F12 and insert this into the console:

```
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php",
            //dataType: "json",
            data: { json: order },
            success: function(data) {
               console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is the order here near data : {json : order}

Comment: @Sabarish That is from the question `var order = [];`