# Failing to return what I want via ajax (Google Geocoding)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have 5 input fields, one for each day of the week. They're saved on `keyup` into a variable, which is working according to `console.log`.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("Ready!");
        $("input[type='text']").keyup(function() {
            console.log("Something changed");

            var mon = $("#mon").val();
            var tue = $("#tue").val();
            var wed = $("#wed").val();
            var thu = $("#thu").val();
            var fri = $("#fri").val();

            console.log("Monday means:" + mon);

            $.ajax({
              type: "post",
              url: "map.php",
              data: 'mon=' + mon + '&tue=' + tue + '&wed=' + wed + '&thu=' + thu + '&fri=' + fri,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data){
                console.log("Your data is:" + data);
              },  
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, I am failing to return either an "Not working" or what I'm actually after. Shouldn't "Not working" be returned if the API call within the php file failed?

```
// This is not returning anything
if($_POST['mon']) {
    $mon = $_POST['mon'];

    // Working fine manually entered into the web browser
    $urlMon = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$mon."&key=myKey123";
    $jsonMon = json_decode(file_get_contents($urlMon), true);
    $address = $jsonMon['results']['formatted_address'];

    if(isset($address)) {
        echo json_encode($address);
    } else {
        echo json_encode("Not working");
    }
}
```

I know that the ajax itself is working, because this is working:

```
// This returns the variable I sent according to the console log.
if($_POST['mon']) {
    $mon = $_POST['mon'];
    echo json_encode($mon);
}
```

I'm quite new at this, I'm sure I've missed something obvious/done something really wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the AJAX requesting erroring?

Comment: First of all, JSON is usually used to pass arrays from PHP to JS, if you are only returning strings, no need to use JSON. Secondly, your syntax to pass datas is not correct, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085649/ajax-multiple-data

Comment: @chris85 No, does not seem so.

Comment: Response is a `200` then and just empty? Try adding `else { echo "It's empty";}` after the last `}`.

Comment: @NicolasP. Just doing monday atm, but I will encode an array of 5 days later on, but first it'd be good to have just one day working

Comment: When I test that, I get the "Not working" output.

Comment: @chris85 Well, I don't have an error function within the ajax itself (because I didn't quite understand it tbh). The console logs nothing, anyway.

Comment: @PatrickQ Really? Huh. Now I'm even more confused..

Comment: what is 'results' in PHP line 7?

Comment: Just for fun, try removing `dataType: 'json',` and see if you get anything.  Since you're encoding just a plain string, it's possible that it's not being viewed as json.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Looks like I missed a `[0]` there, right?

Comment: @PatrickQ What does this suggest: `Your data is:<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 0 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\kickassStuff\map.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
"Not working"`? Removed dataType.

Comment: It suggests that you need to figure out where in that array the address you want is  :)

Comment: @PatrickQ `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Motown` - if I want `formatted_address`, wouldn't that be `$jsonMon['results'][0]['formatted_address'];`?

Comment: Yes, that should work (and does for me).

Comment: @PatrickQ Thanks, it's working for some reason now. Now I just have to figure out why it stops searches when I add a space into the box.. "Mostreet" gets me an address, but when I write "Mostreet Burma" or whichever of the many Mostreets I want the console.log of the data doesn't change

Comment: @PatrickQ Nevermind, forgot to urlencode it. Jesus what's wrong with me today

Comment: @PatrickQ Can you put something you've said as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you weren't seeing anything from your `console.log()` call is because you were explicitly telling jQuery to expect a json result.  And, even though you were calling `json_encode()` on your error text, it it was still really just plain text that jQuery wasn't interpreting as json.  Since you told it to expect json and it wasn't getting it, the `success` callback wasn't happening.  Remove `dataType: 'json',` unless you a.) know that you will *always* get a json response or b.) have an error callback as well.

The reason why we were hitting your error condition is because `$jsonMon['results']['formatted_address']` should have been `$jsonMon['results'][0]['formatted_address']`.  You also need to urlencode the address that you are sending to the maps API.

Answer (score 0):

I see two errors:

```
$address = $jsonMon['results']['formatted_address'];
```

Should be

```
$address = $jsonMon['results'][0]['formatted_address'];
```

to receive the first result.

Second, change

```
} else {
    echo json_encode("Not working");
}
```

to

```
} else {
    echo "Not working";
}
```

and you should be good.

Answer (score -2):

*You have to write like this*

```
$urlMon= file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$mon."&key=myKey123");
$results = json_decode($urlMon,true);
echo $results['results'][0]['formatted_address'];
```

Comment: No I don't? Took that line from another script I have which is working

Comment: `$jsonMon = json_decode(file_get_contents($urlMon), true);` - There's nothing wrong with that part still, that is not the error here