# onclick twice ajax refresh div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This code below only works if i click on the button twice and I've got no clue why it does that.

Any hints would be appreciated. guess it's a .click function that's missing ?

```
<button onclick="getSummary('1');">button</button>

function getSummary(id)
    {
       $.ajax({ type: "GET",
                url: 'ajax_test.php',
                data: "user=<?php echo $_GET['user'];?>",
                success: function(data) {
        $('#summary').html(data);}
        });
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps the first Ajax call is failing, but you only have `success:` so you wouldn't notice. Add `error:` and see if it goes there. As a side, it is always recommended to specify the type (e.g. `type="button"`) for the `<button>` element.

Comment: Thanks! totally forgot about `error:` for troubleshooting !

Comment: As it stands your code works pretty fine and it fires after a first click returning the response. perhaps... https://stackoverflow.com/a/6085669/383904 ? Always log your error responses (as suggested), read the [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6085669/383904) and make sure to pass the correct data. P.S: what's the `'1'` in `getSummary('1');` ? You never use it.

Comment: got it to work now got one question if you guys know a good solution load the ajax when page starts I've got this code at the moment and i want to have it load when page loads.

`function getSummary()
 {
  $("button").click(function(){ $.ajax({ type: "GET",
        url: 'ajax_test.php',
        data: "user=<?php echo $_GET['user'];?>",
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
         $('#summary').html(data); },
        error: function() {
         alert("something went wrong while sending data to server");}
       });
     });
  }`

Comment: Don't post code in comments, it's very hard to read. Edit your question and add it there if it is related. If not, start another question.