# How to pass parameters with value using @url.Action using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I want to pass the values I get from my elements to the controller using Javascript. I want to pass `startdate`, `enddate` and `true` if the `region` checkbox is checked.

Please note that the script also performs an extract functionality which is already working. I just want to know how I can pass those three parameters to the controller. Thanks

```js
$(function() {
  var startdate = document.getElementById("StartDate").value;
  var endDate = document.getElementById("EndDate").value;
  var regionname = document.getElementById("RegionName").checked;
  console.log(regionname);
  
  $("#btn-go").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: '@Url.Action("GenerateExporttReport", "Reports")',
      xhrFields: {
        responseType: 'blob'
      },
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result)
        var blob = result;
        var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = downloadUrl;
        a.download = "downloadFile.xlsx";
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```csharp
public FileContentResult GenerateExportReport(string startdate, string endDate, bool regionname)
{
  // Code already exists here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `data` property of the `$.ajax()` method settings. jQuery will recognise the GET HTTP verb and add them to the querystring for you.

Also note that you need to read the values of the form controls ***inside*** the click handler, otherwise the values will be what they were when the page loaded, not when the button was clicked. Try this:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: '@Url.Action("GenerateExporttReport", "Reports")',
  xhrFields: {
    responseType: 'blob'
  },
  data: {
    startDate: $('#StartDate').val(),
    endDate: $('#EndDate').val(),
    regionName: $('#RegionName').prop('checked')
  },
  success: //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085649/how-to-send-multiple-data-fields-via-ajax)

You're looking for the "data" option.

```
 $(function () {
            var startdate = document.getElementById("StartDate").value;
            var endDate = document.getElementById("EndDate").value;
            var regionname = document.getElementById("RegionName").checked;
        
            console.log(regionname);
           $("#btn-go").click(function () {
               $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: '@Url.Action("GenerateExporttReport", "Reports")',
                   data: {startdate : startdate, endDate : endDate, regionname : regionname  },
                xhrFields: {
                   responseType: 'blob'
               },
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result)
                var blob = result;
                var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                a.href = downloadUrl;
                a.download = "downloadFile.xlsx";
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
            }
        });
       });
    });
```