# Why a different result of a PHP for loop when loaded with Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

I load data onto a page using Ajax.

Here is the div (saleContentData) into which it is loaded:

```
                <div class="resultsPage salesList">
                    <h2>Sales</h2>
                    <div class="salesFilters">
                        <form action="" method="POST">
                            <label for="date1">Start Date</label>
                            <input id="startDate" type="date" name="date1" value="Start Date" placeholder="Start Date" value="" min="1997-01-01" max="2030-12-31" />
                            <label for="date2">End Date</label>
                            <input id="endDate" type="date" name="date2" value="End Date" placeholder="End Date" value="" min="01-01-2010" max="01-01-2030" />
                            <button id="filterSales">Filter Sales</button>
                            <button id="resetFilter">Reset</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class=" salesContent">
                        <div class="saleContentData">
                            <div id="loading">
                                <img id="loading-image" src="assets/img/loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is the the script to display the data.

```
if (isset($_POST['start_date']) && $_POST['end_date']) {
    $startDate = $_POST['start_date'];
    $endDate = $_POST['end_date'];
    $page_size = $_POST['page_size'];
    $page_num = $_POST['page_num'];
    showFiltered($startDate, $endDate, $page_size, $page_num);
} else if (isset($_POST['page_size']) && $_POST['page_num']) {
    $page_size = $_POST['page_size'];
    $page_num = $_POST['page_num'];
    showNormal($page_size, $page_num);
} else {
    showNormal();
}

function showNormal($page_number = 1, $page_size = 100)
{
    //THE DATA
    $data = getData("https://api.someapi.com/v2/sales?page_size=" . $page_size . "&page_number=" . $page_number);
    //SHOW THE DATA
    showRecords($data);
}

function showRecords($data)
{
    //STATISTICS ABOUT THE DATA
    $total_sales = ($data['page_summary']['total']);
    $current_page = $data['page_summary']['page_number'];
    echo $total_sales . " sales<br/>";
    $num_pages = (ceil($total_sales / 100) * 100) / 100;
    echo "<ul>";
// TO DISPLAY THE NUMBER OF PAGES
    for ($page = 0; $page < $num_pages; $page++) {
        if ($page == $current_page - 1) {
            echo "<li class='page$page active'>" . $page + 1 . "</li>";
        } else {
            echo "<li class='page$page'>" . $page + 1 . "</li>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    // TABLE WITH ALL SALES RECORDS
    $sales = $data['sales'];
    $counter = 1;
    echo "<table id='salesTable'>
        <thead><tr class='headingRow'><th class='image'></th><th class='productHD'>Product</th><th>Status</th><th>Revenue</th><th>Quantity</th><th class='dcCol'>DC</th><th>Order ID</th><th>Customer Name</th><th>Date</th></tr></thead>";
    foreach ($sales as $key => $row) {
        $col1 = $row['selling_price'];
        $col2 = $row['quantity'];
        $revenue = ($col1 * $col2);
        echo "<tr><td class='num centerCol'><img src='placeholder.png'/></td><td class='productTitle'>" . $row['product_title'] . "</td><td class='centerCol'>" . $row['sale_status'] . "</td><td class='centerCol'>" . "R" . $revenue . "</td><td class='centerCol'>" . $row['quantity']  . "</td><td class='centerCol'>" . $row['dc'] . "</td><td class='centerCol'>" . $row['offer_id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['customer'] . "</td><td>" . $row['order_date'] . "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Here is the Javscript that loads the page into the div:

```
  $(".goSale").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "getsales.php",
      success: function (data) {
        $(".saleContentData").html(data);
      },
      error: function (request, status, error) {
        $(".saleContentData").html(error);
      },
      complete: function () {},
    });
  });
```

if I run the file by itself the list with the page numbers is displayed correctly and I see 1 TO 7. If I load the file using Ajax I get a different result and the page numbers are displayed as seven 1s.

Why would this be please?

So after looking at the HTML I see the list is not being generated and the numbers are loaded in the  tag and so there is not list items.

Why would that be?

Does Ajax remove something?

Loading the page by itself
[image: loading the page by itself]

Loading the page using Ajax
[image: loading the page using Ajax]

Solved it:

```
    echo "<ul id='pagesList'>";
    for ($page = 0; $page < $num_pages; $page++) {
        echo "<li class='page$page'>";
        echo $page + 1;
        echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>
```

Comment: Maybe the data appended broke the html in some way ( the style is different ).

Comment: The style is different because loading the file by itself no CSS is applied, while loading it with Ajax the main CSS of the site is applied.

Answer (score -1):

The problem might be that you did not send any data to `getsales.php` page.

Check something like this.

[How to send multiple data fields via Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085649/how-to-send-multiple-data-fields-via-ajax)

If script you showed for displaying data is `getsales.php`, then you need to send there some data as below via ajax.

```
if (isset($_POST['start_date']) && $_POST['end_date']) {
    $startDate = $_POST['start_date'];
    $endDate = $_POST['end_date'];
    $page_size = $_POST['page_size'];
    $page_num = $_POST['page_num'];
}
showFiltered($startDate, $endDate, $page_size, $page_num);
```

Comment: I don't need to send any data to getsales.php because if I do not send any data it just displays all records, which is what I am doing here.